# How do I evaluate this derivative in a well-known maximum likelihood derivation?

Tags: derivatives, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I have been trying for some considerable time to derive a very widely used result in the field of (wireless) direction-finding, namely the Maximum Likelihood direction estimate (based on a simple, standard signal model).

After much searching, the best references I could find were [this review article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01812401) (behind a paywall) and, to a lesser extent, [this one](http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/88622/1/88622.pdf) (free). However, I still get stuck on one of the differentiations. This is possibly so simple that no background is required, but I'll show my working:

---

> We have a matrix $\boldsymbol{X}\in\mathbb{C}^{p\times M}$ comprising
>   $M$ discrete measurements from an array of $p$ antennas. According to
>   the signal model, $\boldsymbol{X}$ has the following structure:
>   $$\boldsymbol{X}=\boldsymbol{A}\left(\underline{\theta}\right)\boldsymbol{S}+\boldsymbol{N}\tag{1}$$ where
>   $\boldsymbol{A}\left(\underline{\theta}\right)=[\underline{a}(\theta_1),
> \dots,\underline{a}(\theta_q)]$ and the value of the "steering vector"
>   $\underline{a}(\theta)\in\mathbb{C^{p\times1}}$ is known for any
>   $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, but
>   $\underline{\theta}=[\theta_1,\dots,\theta_q]^T$ is unknown (to be
>   estimated). The matrix $\boldsymbol{S}\in\mathbb{C}^{q\times M}$ is
>   deterministic and unknown (and we don't care about finding out its
>   values). The random noise $\boldsymbol{N}$ has various nice properties
>   to simplify the analysis (see assumptions below):
>
> [image: Assumptions]
>
> Based on this model, the joint PDF of the columns of $\boldsymbol{X}$
>   is apparently:$$f(\boldsymbol{X})=\prod_{i=1}^M\frac{1}{\pi
> \det(\sigma^2\boldsymbol{I})}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\lVert
> \underline{x}(t_i)-\boldsymbol{A}\left(\underline{\theta}\right)\underline{s}(t_i)\rVert^2\right)
> \tag{2}$$
>
> (However, based on [other reading](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/foundation-in-digital-communication/05F46005A017815C49810D51CFDB9B8F), I can't see why the $\pi$ isn't
>   $\pi^p$). Nonetheless, the log-likelihood function (ignoring constant
>   terms) is:$$\mathcal{L}=-Mp\ln\sigma^2-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^M
> \lVert
> \underline{x}(t_i)-\boldsymbol{A}\left(\underline{\theta}\right)\underline{s}(t_i)
> \rVert^2 \tag{3}$$
>
> Fixing $\underline{\theta}$ and $\underline{s}$ and maximizing with
>   respect to $\sigma^2$: $$ \hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{Mp}\sum_{i=1}^M
> \lVert
> \underline{x}(t_i)-\boldsymbol{A}\left(\underline{\theta}\right)\underline{s}(t_i)
> \rVert^2 \tag{4}$$ Substituting this back in to (3), we get (ignoring
>   constant terms, and the monotonic $\ln(\cdot)$): $$ -\sum_{i=1}^M
> \lVert
> \underline{x}(t_i)-\boldsymbol{A}\left(\underline{\theta}\right)\underline{s}(t_i)
> \rVert^2 \tag{5}$$

---

The next step is to maximize this expression (5) with respect to $\underline{s}$. I'm a bit confused as to what this even means, when (5) contains $\underline{s}(t_i)$, not $\underline{s}$. The only thing I could think is if we could assume the $\left\{\underline{s}(t_i)\right\}$ are independent, then differentiating with respect to some $\underline{s} \triangleq \underline{s}(t_j)$ would, I think, give:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \underline{s}(t_j)}\underline{s}(t_i)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{I},\quad i=j \\ 
\mathbf{0},\quad i\neq j%
\end{array}%
\right. $$
and then the $\sum_{i=1}^M$ would basically disappear. However, I'm not sure if this is correct, or even if the assumption of independence makes any sense.

The reference provided for solving this step is [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2156365?seq=1) (good typesetting, but behind a paywall) or [this paper](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/72/261/CS-TR-72-261.pdf) (the same paper for free, but worse typesetting). However, it is written in mathematical language that I can't make any sense of.

Can anyone help me to get past this step?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the stated assumptions vs. what is trying to be estimated.  Perhaps it's the terminology, but assumption (5) states that the signals are deterministic parameters to be estimated, and (6) the direction vectors are known for all directions (theta).  So, based on that, it seems like the problem is set up to find the values of "s" which maximize the log-likelihood of observing the measurements X, given full knowledge of A (the matrix of direction/steering vectors).  I might be off base here, but a bit confused as to the goals of the optimization. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: A common example would be that theta is a scalar between 0 and 2pi radians. We can trace out the locus of the direction vector a(theta) across all possible values of theta and this will form some curve in p-dimensional complex space. This curve is fully known (and we should be able to use this knowledge to estimate which q values of theta took part in generating X). S may be estimated, but only if doing so helps to estimate theta.

Comment: Technically, differentiating by $s(t_j)$ is fine, and indeed you will get $(x(t_j)-A(\theta)s(t_j))^T A(\theta) =0$ which will induce an equation for $s(t_j)$.

Comment: @user721481 Could you elaborate at all?

Comment: As you said, differentiating by $s(t_j)$ selects a single term form the sum, and then demanding $\partial_{s(t_j)} ||x(tj)−A(\theta)s(t_j)||^2=0$  yields $A^t x=A^TAs$

Comment: @user721481 Does this rely on making any new assumption about $s$? Or does it follow directly? For example, if all the elements of the vector $\underline{s}(t)$ could be identical, then I think the derivatives would all be 1, not 0 (unless I am misunderstanding the meaning of the differentiation? I am confused about whether the variable is $t$ or $t_j$, and whether this matters.). So, if I understand correctly, we are saying the $s_i(t)$ must be independent.

Comment: I am a little fuzzy as to whether you mean $s$ to be given or to be estimated. If is is to be estimated, then indeed they can be taked to be independent/

Comment: @user721481 The $s_i$ are "to be estimated" (if required). We don't directly care what they are, but in principle could estimate them as part of the main goal of estimating the $\theta_i$. (I think the $s_i$ can therefore be referred to as "nuisance parameters".) Is it obvious why they can be assumed to be independent? I feel like we don't know anything about them, so they could be dependent or independent. But I'm not totally sure what "dependence" means here. Could $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$ be "independent", but have identical values for all $t$?